# Suggested tag wiki edit proposes a new tag for a 3rd party software package - should I approve?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Now I am allowed to review tag wiki edits (Ask Ubuntu just gets more and more fun) ^_^

But at the first one I ever come across, I am uncertain O.O

Here's [the suggested edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/601609) in question.

The user proposed creating a new tag for a software package which, as far as I know:

- is not in repositories or on Launchpad but
- has a Linux version and
- can be successfully installed in Ubuntu (there are pages on the website about doing so)

I'm not sure whether this tag is useful or not. I asked in chat, and a great AU guru advised me to reject, but I thought I would ask here, in case it might help others...

Comment: I recommend following Guru's advice.

Comment: I did so of course @AnwarShah - thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I feel this particular tag wiki edit should be rejected.

In general, consider approving edits to tag wiki if the tag is popular (minimum 5 questions tagged). If there is only one question with that tag, there is a good chance of that tag getting purged from the system and it's not worth the effort to write one up.

There are also some general guidelines on what makes a good tag wiki that I wrote earlier and you can consider them when reviewing tag wiki edits.(frankly, I don't recall writing them but the system says so.)

- [What makes a tag wiki "good"?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/3977/what-makes-a-tag-wiki-good)